# No se de donde sale &bookingButtonPc= en la url

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo un DatePicker y todo funciona como pretendía, se me está metiendo &bookingButtonPc= al final de la url, y no se de donde sale, agradezco la ayuda.

Es un formulario en .html con Flatpickr js para construir el range calendar y los estilos por defecto, he modificado con las especificaciones de witbooking, todo funciona correctamente como se esperaba, pero me tiene frito este detalle.

Aquí se puede ver corriendo: https://imorillas.com/witbooking/index.html

```
function submitForm() {
  var form = document.querySelector(".reservation-form");
  var datein = document.getElementById("datein").value;
  var dateout = document.getElementById("dateout").value;
  var habitacion = document.getElementById("habitacion").value;
  var adultos = document.getElementById("adultos").value;
  var ninos = document.getElementById("ninos").value;
  var url = "https://example.com/reservar";
  url += "?affiliate=" + encodeURIComponet(affiliate);
  url += "&datein=" + encodeURIComponent(datein);
  url += "&dateout=" + encodeURIComponent(dateout);
  url += "&habitacion=" + encodeURIComponent(habitacion);
  url += "&adultos=" + encodeURIComponent(adultos);
  url += "&ninos=" + encodeURIComponent(ninos);
```

```
  form.action = url;
  form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Es exactamente el `name` del botón que estás presionando, quitale el name al botón o definelo de una manera distinta para que no vaya incluido en la URL

Comment: Hola Antonio, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu sitio web se puede apreciar que tienes incluido en tu botón 'Ver Disponibilidad' el atributo name="bookingButtonPc".

Y cuando se ejecuta el envío del formulario se agrega. Este es un atributo que es recomendable únicamente utilizar para aquellos atributos que posean algún tipo de dato o información.

Con eliminarlo se soluciona tu problemática.